# How can I incoporate terra objects in the output list of a function?

Tags: r, terra

I am currently updating the [`virtualspecies`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=virtualspecies) R package to shift from `raster` to `terra`.

In this package I used to ship rasters from the package `raster` in the output list of functions. These outputs were a simple list with an appended class called `virtualspecies` where one to two elements of the list were objects of class `RasterLayer` or `RasterStack`.

For example, here is how an output object was created in this package, [taken from here](https://github.com/Farewe/virtualspecies/blob/36c079b3c853b77df46573ca46adff5abd253d56/R/generateSpFromPCA.R#L293C1-L301C62):

```
  results <- list(approach = "pca",
                  details = list(variables = sel.vars,
                                 pca = pca.object,
                                 rescale = rescale,
                                 axes = axes, 
                                 means = means,
                                 sds = sds),
                  suitab.raster = suitab.raster)
  class(results) <-  append("virtualspecies", class(results))
```

`suitab.raster` in this example was an object of class `RasterLayer`.

These `virtualspecies` objects are part of a workflow of functions where the next function would take the raster(s) from the list, make new calculations, and oftentimes add another raster into the output list. These objects could be exported with e.g. `saveRDS()` and kept their functionality.

To shift this package from `raster` to `terra`, my question is:
**How can I incorporate `terra` objects into simple output lists from a function in a way that ensures these objects remain self-contained and can be easily transferred between different R sessions or computers?**

*Note that I would like to keep the objects self-contained as much as possible, since this is one of the arguments we used in the [paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/ecog.01388) where we introduced the virtualspecies package:*

> "the generated virtual species can be stored on the hard disk drive and provided in online supplementary materials of articles"

I am currently considering three possibilities:

1. Use the `wrap()` function from package `terra` to store `spatRasters` objects in output lists. This would probably imply to often wrap/unwrap objects between functions of the package. However, as far as I understood (I am only starting on this aspect) I would probably need to use `proxy = FALSE` to ensure that objects are self-contained and portable, which could be problematic for large rasters or low memory computers.
2. Use `writeRaster()` and try to keep track of the locations where the rasters are saved in the output list. In that case the objects would no longer be self-contained. In addition, I am reluctant on writing files on the disk because I am not very familiar with the best practices of doing that inside a package, and how to ensure the objects will be portable across OS without adding too much complexity for users.
3. Use a combination of 1. and 2.: use `wrap()` as the preferred method, but when it is not memory-safe or simply fails, then use `writeRaster()` and keep track of the locations where the file were written so that the object can be re-read into R memory when a function needs to access the raster.

Which of these approaches (or one not mentioned above) is objectively the best and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I have opted for solution #1, wrapping terra objects in the output list as follows:

```
results <- list(approach = "pca",
                details = list(variables = sel.vars,
                               pca = pca.object,
                               rescale = rescale,
                               axes = axes, 
                               means = means,
                               sds = sds),
                suitab.raster = wrap(suitab.raster,
                                     proxy = FALSE))
class(results) <-  append("virtualspecies", class(results))
```

And I added generic functions to `$` and `[[` so that when users want to access the rasters they will get an unwrapped raster, rather than a wrapped raster.

By doing so I also unintentionally made the rest of the code much easier, since I don't have to add `unwrap()` everytime I want to access a raster object from one of these lists.

Here is how I added these generics to automatically unwrap terra objects when accessed with `$` or `[[`.

```
#' @export
#' @method `$` virtualspecies
`$.virtualspecies` <- function(x, name)
{
  if(inherits(as.list(x)[[name]], "PackedSpatRaster")) {
    return(unwrap(`[[`(as.list(x), name)))
  } else {
    return(`[[`(as.list(x), name))
  }
}

#' @export
#' @method `[[` virtualspecies
`[[.virtualspecies` <- function(x, name)
{
  if(inherits(as.list(x)[[name]], "PackedSpatRaster")) {
    return(unwrap(`[[`(as.list(x), name)))
  } else {
    return(`[[`(as.list(x), name))
  }
}

#' @export
#' @method `as.list` virtualspecies
as.list.virtualspecies <- function(x)
{
  class(x) <- "list"
  return(x)
}
```

This code works, but I am still uncertain about two aspects:

1. What will happen if users try to `wrap()` very large rasters? I am not yet sure how to handle this situation.
2. I wonder if the way I wrote the generic `$` and `[[` functions is adequate and will not cause issues in cases I have not tried yet.